# Is it possible to search for two dataframe columns's values in another dataframe's column and return an ID where there are matches?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function, for-loop

I have two datasets. One has survey information and the other one has complaints. I am trying to see if the people who took surveys are mentioned in the description of the complaint. There is a column for first and last name in the survey df. My intention is to use a contains function to check the complaints description column for a match on the first and last name. I would then like to add the survey id to the complaints dataset where there is a match.

Survey data:

| survey_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| survey1 | John | Smith |

Complaint Data:

| complaint_number | description |
| --- | --- |
| complaint1 | John Wick is a great movie |
| complaint2 | Jason Smith stinks |
| complaint3 | John Smith is awesome! |

Expected Result of the new complaint df:

| complaint_number | Description | matches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| complaint1 | John Wick is a great movie |  |
| complaint2 | Jason Smith stinks |  |
| complaint3 | John Smith is awesome! | survey1 |

Comment: Does the complaints df need to find an exact match for 'john smith', or would the 2 names separated by text be a match? Eg. Would "the second name of John is Smith" be a match or not?

Comment: They can be anywhere in the text in case their last name comes before their first in the complaint. I expect a small output dataset so I would do some manual filtering after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes exact match on first and last as full name (see new 'pattern' column), and doesn't look to see if two full names are in the description, but this is a start if you need to modify it.

```
import io

d1 = '''survey_id   first_name  last_name
survey1 John    Smith
survey2 John    Wick
'''
df_survey = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(d1), sep=' \s+', engine='python')
df_survey

d2 = '''complaint_number    description
complaint1  John Wick is a great movie
complaint2  Jason Smith stinks
complaint3  John Smith is awesome!
complaint4  John Wick is awesome!
'''
df_complaints = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(d2), sep=' \s+', engine='python')

df_survey['pattern'] =  df_survey.apply( lambda x: ' '.join([x['first_name'], x['last_name']]), axis=1)
df_complaints['matches'] = ''

def find_matches(x):
    sid = x['survey_id']
    # print(sid, x['pattern'])
    df_complaints['matches'].loc[df_complaints['description'].str.contains(x['pattern'], case=False)] = sid
    return None

df_survey.apply(lambda x: find_matches(x), axis=1)
df_complaints
```

Output

```
  complaint_number                 description  matches
0       complaint1  John Wick is a great movie  survey2
1       complaint2          Jason Smith stinks
2       complaint3      John Smith is awesome!  survey1
3       complaint4       John Wick is awesome!  survey2
```

Comment: Thank you! With some small modifications I got the expected behavior I was anticipating. I just added logic to append multiple surveys in case someone was mentioned twice.